# Is it possible to exclude first n values in each window when using rolling() to get the maximum value?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [150, 106, 119, 131, 121, 140, 160, 119, 170]})
```

And this is the expected output. I want to create column `b`:

```
     a      b
0  150      140
1  106      160
2  119      160
3  131      161 
4  121      NaN
5  140      NaN
6  160      NaN
7  119      NaN
8  170      NaN
```

I want to get the maximum value in a rolling window of 6. However I want to ignore the first value of each window.

In this picture I have shown the windows that I want. Red cells are the ones that should be excluded from calculations and green ones are the maximum value of the window that are in `b`.

[image]

I prefer a generic solution. For example getting `max()` after ignoring first N values of each window.

These are some of my attempts that did not work:

```
# attempt 1
df['b'] = df.a.shift(-1).rolling(6).max()
# attempt 2
df['b'] = df.a.rolling(6, closed='left').max()
# attempt 3 
for i in range(3):
    x = df.iloc[i+1:i+6]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The naive approach would be to use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html) and drop the first item:

```
N = 6
df['out'] = df.loc[::-1, 'a'].rolling(N).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1].max())
```

However, since your operation is independent of this value, better compute the [`rolling.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.max.html) on `N-1` and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) after the fact. Which can simplify the code to:

```
N = 6
df['out'] = df.loc[::-1, 'a'].rolling(N-1).max().shift()
```

*Note that since `rolling` uses the **previous** values by default, we need to first **invert** the order of the Series with `[::-1]`.*

Output:

```
     a    out
0  150  140.0
1  106  160.0
2  119  160.0
3  131  170.0
4  121    NaN
5  140    NaN
6  160    NaN
7  119    NaN
8  170    NaN
```

##### generalization

To generalize to skipping `skip` values:

```
N = 6
skip = 2

df['out'] = df.loc[::-1, 'a'].rolling(N-skip).max().shift(skip)
```

Example (changing the second `119` to `118` for clarity):

```
     a  skip=0  skip=1  skip=2  skip=3  skip=4  skip=5  skip=6
0  150   150.0   140.0   140.0   140.0   140.0   140.0     NaN
1  106   160.0   160.0   160.0   160.0   160.0   160.0     NaN
2  119   160.0   160.0   160.0   160.0   160.0   118.0     NaN
3  131   170.0   170.0   170.0   170.0   170.0   170.0     NaN
4  121     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
5  140     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
6  160     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
7  118     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
8  170     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I want to ignore first two values instead of first value, `shift(2)` should be used?

Comment: Yes and `N-2` in `rolling`

Comment: Sorry for the typo. You are the best :)